# How to append div follow the number

Tags: javascript, html, json

i want it show after get the value > or == with the value then show.
And the value is get by ajax:

1.how to display below div with the value?

```css
.mainbox{
width:auto;
height:auto;
padding:20px;
background:#f00;
}
.innerbox{
width:100%;
height:100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <div id="01" class="innerbox" style="display:block" value="100">
    <span>you have 100 point</span>
  </div>
  <div id="02" class="innerbox" style="display:block" value="150">
    <button type="button">get your point 150</button>
  </div>
  <div id="03" class="innerbox" style="display:none" value="200">
  </div>
  <div id="04" class="innerbox" style="display:none" value="250">
  </div>
  <div id="05" class="innerbox" style="display:none" value="300">
  </div>
  <div id="06" class="innerbox" style="display:none" value="350">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what? is the question

Comment: sorry just dont know how to write here

Comment: ok..thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do but from the code it looks like you want the points to increase by 50 every time the button is clicked. I modified your HTML a bit to show one way you can do it.

Important part to understand is how to retrieve the element from the document with methods like

```
document.getElementById(id)
```

Once you can access the element then you can start changing or manipulating data. You can read more about the DOM and methods [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

```css
.mainbox{
width:auto;
height:auto;
padding:20px;
background:#f00;
}
.innerbox{
width:100%;
height:100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainbox">
  <div id="1" class="innerbox" style="display:block" value="100">
    <p id="exampleElement">You have 100 points</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="innerbox" style="display:block">
    <button type="button" onclick="handleButtonClick()">get your points</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
const handleButtonClick = () => {
  let el = document.getElementById('exampleElement');
   //here you are saying your target element is 'exampleElement' 
  let num = el.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g,'')
   //here we use Regex to strip the string of all letters, leaving only the number
  num = parseInt(num) + 50;
   //here we convert the string to an int and add 50
  el.innerHTML = `You have ${num} points`;
   //here we tell the target element to update with a new string
}
</script>
```